# wp_trim_words is trimming by character instead of by words

Tags: excerpt

I'm using Wordpress 3.9.2, and having trouble with the `wp_trim_words` function.  It seems to be cutting the string down to X characters instead of X words.

**Example**

Put the following in a template file:

```
<?php 
$str = "Imagine discovering a secret language spoken only online by a knowledgeable and learned few. Over a period of weeks, as you begin to tease out the meaning of this curious tongue and ponder its purpose, the language appears to shift in subtle but fantastic ways, remaking itself daily before your eyes. And just when you are poised to share your findings with the rest of the world, the entire thing vanishes.";

$str_excerpt = wp_trim_words($str, $num_words = 5, $more = '...' );

echo $str_excerpt;
?>
```

In my browser, I see the output as `Imagi...`.  That's not how it should function though, as far as I read from [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words):

> Description
>
> This function trims text to a certain number of words and
>   returns the trimmed text.
>
> Usage
>
> $trimmed = wp_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 55, $more = null);

Is there a setting or perhaps something in the theme I'm using that's causing this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like something has added a filter to set the word count method to characters. This is usually only done in the case of languages such as Chinese where each character is a word. What language are you using for the blog?

Comment: My `wp-config.php` file has `define('WPLANG', '');`, which means I'm defaulting to English, as desired.

Comment: Do you have anything on the site that isn't English in any way? Anything that might have something to do with translations?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use  [mb_strimwidth](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) function for trim the characters instead of words.

```
echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 40, '...');
```